# What is this diamond of every day?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

*Part of the [everyday object series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=body%3A%22everyday+object+series%22+is%3Aquestion)*

> You are the diamond of every day,
>   but in leaky containers you're stored away.
>   You slumber 'neath mountains, float in the sea,
>   Too much of you kills, too little equally,
>   It's not your glimmer, nor smell I desire,
>   but a day without you is bland entire.

What is this diamond of every day?

*The lyrical identity could be any person.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you are

> salt.

You are the diamond of every day,

> Salt forms crystals, albeit not of the same shape as the crystals we call diamonds.

but in leaky containers you're stored away.

> You probably have such a container in your kitchen right now. Though "leaky" is a bit of a weak point; the containers generally leak only by design.

You slumber 'neath mountains, float in the sea,

> Rock salt and sea salt.

Too much of you kills, too little equally,

> Without salt we would die (this is the main way it's bad if you drink waaaaay too much water). With too much, too.

It's not your glimmer, nor smell I desire,

> Salt crystals aren't particularly shiny, and they have no smell at all.

but a day without you is bland entire.

> But the *taste* of salt is pleasing and without it lots of foods would taste bland.

Comment: Well done, I like this answer much better!

Answer (score 4):

I kinda liked

> Fresh water

You are the diamond of every day

> Fresh water is metaphorically diamond like (exceedingly valuable in an absolute sense, also sparkly, crystal clear)

but in leaky containers you're stored away.

> Aquifers leak. As do reservoirs, rivers and bloodstreams and glands in living bodies. Its kinda hard to find fresh water in places that *aren't* leaky containers.

You slumber 'neath mountains,

> Fresh water can be trapped underground, especially under impervious rock.

... float in the sea,

> It's lighter than salt water so it floats in salt water, especially in the form of icebergs.

Too much of you kills, too little equally,

> Yes. Obvious is obvious ;)

It's not your glimmer, nor smell I desire,

> Its the water itself, not its appearance or non-scent, one desires, when you want a drink.

but a day without you is bland entire.

> The world becomes "bland" entirely, when too thirsty... and a day without anything to drink is enough to make one very thirsty.

Comment: Oh, I like this answer very much! I wrote this riddle with ROT13(fnyg va zvaq), but yours fits perfectly, too.

Answer (score 1):

Is this

> Oxygen?

You are the diamond of every day,

> It’s a big part of every one of my days, because of breathing.

but in leaky containers you're stored away.

> Oxygen can be stored in tanks, which either leak accidentally or purposefully, the second type is used for underwater breathing.

You slumber 'neath mountains, float in the sea,

> There are oxygen bubbles probably trapped in magma underneath mountains, and oxygen bubbles float to the surface of the sea.

Too much of you kills, too little equally,

> Love is like oxygen...you get too much you get on high, not enough and you’re gonna die... (oxygen toxicity/hyperoxia is a real medical problem that isn’t pleasant; hypoxia means you have nothing to breathe; either kills).

It's not your glimmer, nor smell I desire,

> Oxygen doesn’t have a glimmer or smell.

but a day without you is bland entire.

> Because you’d probably die.

Comment: Nice answer, but unfortunately wrong.